# What file permissions should the contents of $GIT_DIR have?

Tags: git

I have restored a git repo from backup and it does not have the correct file permissions. Is it enough to set owner +rw on all files and directories in .git, or is it more subtle?

Is there a utility to check or reset .git file permissions?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Directories should have 755 permission; files should have 644 permission.

That's a pretty good rule of thumb unless you expect members of your group to make changes to your repository.

Having said that, in one of my repositories, the files under `.git/objects/*` have 444 (readonly) permission for everyone.  Other files are 644 as suggested.

This script, run in the top-level directory just above the `.git` repository would fix the permissions:

```
 find .git -type d | xargs chmod 755
 find .git/objects -type f | xargs chmod 444
 find .git -type f | grep -v /objects/ | xargs chmod 644
```

I started with `-print0` for the first two `find` commands and `xargs -0` to allow for the remote possibility of spaces in file names.  But the `grep -v` in the third command would be difficult to manage with the `-print0` format - so I omitted the space-safe notation from all the commands, knowing that `git` does not create files with spacing in names under the `.git` directory.

Comment: I had a .git/FETCH_HEAD permission denied message when I ran ```git pull``` no matter what permissions I set on it. This solved the problem and helped me set group permissions. Thanks!

Comment: What is the minimal though.  Can't we go 750 on the dirs, and 440/640  on the objs?  Assuming the env is properly setup, with groups.

Comment: @blamb: The minimum depends on what you want who to be able to do.  It also depends in part on whether you're going to use ACLs (access control lists) to help manage who can do what.  You might get away with 700 permissions; only the user can access the directory.  There is no 'universally correct' answer — there are options depending on your requirements.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ok yeah so i normally dev on a box, then push to prod machine, and i dont like to filemode false, so the security on prod starts on dev. (plus im a one man show, with visions of team collab accessl, shared-hosting in this case, so basic access, you know how apache runs there normally) lets go with that. NO ACLS, since this is a perms method.  advice?  By the way, no probs with my initial recommendation yet (750/440/640), i tested it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3648777/5113030)'s answer, it's worth to mention the ownership of the `.git` and its parent directories, too. For example:

```bash
sudo chown -v "$( id -u; ):$( id -g; )" .;
sudo chown -v "$( id -u; ):$( id -g; )" -R .git;
find '.git' -type d -exec chmod -v 775 {} \;;
find '.git/objects' -type f -exec chmod -v 444 {} \;;
find '.git/hooks' -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec chmod -v 775 {} \;;
find '.git' -type f ! -path '.git/objects/*' ! -path '.git/hooks/*' -exec chmod -v 664 {} \;;
```

---

Related:
[ensure_valid_ownership()](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4654134976fd4d80ea664c159f798f21c7917d8c/setup.c#L1136-L1166)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74209644/5113030 (*git submodule update failed with 'fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at'*...)