# "git submodule update" failed with 'fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at...'

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, filesystems, cve-2022-24765

I mounted a new hard disk drive in my Linux workstation. It looks like it is working well. I want to download some repository in the new disk. So I execute `git clone XXX`, and it works well. But when I [cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) in the folder, and execute `git submodule update --init --recursive`. It failed with

```
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/media/data/users/jhu3szh/serialize'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

git config --global --add safe.directory /media/data/users/jhu3szh/serialize
```

I thought maybe it's just a slight warning, so I just executed `git config --global --add safe.directory /media/data/users/jhu3szh/serialize`. However, when I execute the Git submodule again, more similar errors came out. There are many submodules in the repository.

What is the explanation for what happened?

Comment: Are you sure you have the proper permissions in the directory? Other posts regarding a similar problem suggest that it may be due to lacking permissions.

Comment: @Nox, Well, I  tried execute 'chmod -R 777 .' in the parent folder. It still didn't work. Besides, I just tested touching a file and write something in it is OK.

Comment: It's not a question of the *modes* of files in the repository (though you should definitely *not* set them to 0777 in most cases, so you might want to undo your `chmod` if you can; unfortunately without restoring from backup, that's generally difficult). The complaint instead has to do with *ownership*, i.e., the user-ID who owns each of the various directories.

Comment: You can either ensure that all repositories are owned by the correct owner-ID (by not running *anything* with `sudo` if at all possible), or bypass the security (but if you do that, you're taking some level of risk as shown by the CVE's existence). To fix the ownership of existing repositories, use `chown` to change their ownership to the correct owner. Of course this requires the use of `sudo`—but at least you can use it just once, to fix this condition, and then stop using it...

Comment: To completely bypass the security, add `*` as a "safe" directory (note that this requires a Git version that supports `*`; 2..36 or later does, for instance).

Comment: @HuihuaJiang Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Koithé, not yet

Comment: You can also sudo to the username which owns the git directory (if you have more to do in there). e.g. "sudo su -l rancid -s /bin/bash" (if you're trying to pull an old version of the config out of RANCiD for example)

Comment: In my case ownership was the issue. I think if we copy and paste, the new folder (renaming it to required name)should have ownership and we can easily sort the issue.

Comment: use : sudo git add .

Answer (score 409):

#### Silence all `safe.directory` warnings

##### tl;dr

Silence all warnings related to Git's `safe.directory` system. Be sure to understand what you're doing.

```
git config --global --add safe.directory '*'
```

##### Long version

Adapted from this post on [I cannot add the parent directory to *safe.directory* in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71904131/7964351).

I had the same issue and resolved it by disabling [safe directory](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.35.2#Documentation/git-config.txt-safedirectory) checks, which will end all the "unsafe repository" errors.

This can be done by running the following command<sup>1</sup>:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory '*'
```

Which will add the following setting to your global `.gitconfig` file:

```
[safe]
    directory = *
```

Before disabling, **make sure you understand this security measure**, and [why it exists](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8959555cee7ec045958f9b6dd62e541affb7e7d9). You **should not do this** if your repositories are stored on a shared drive.

However, if you are the sole user of your machine 100% of the time, *and* your repositories are stored locally, then disabling this check should, theoretically, pose no increased risk.

Also note that you can't currently combine this with a file path, which would be relevant in my case. [The command doesn't interpret the wildcard `*` as an operator](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3809#issuecomment-1102681740) per se – it just takes the `"*"` argument to mean "disable safe repository checks/ consider all repositories as safe".

---

<sup>**1** - If this fails in your particular terminal program in Windows, try surrounding the wildcard with double quotes instead of single (Via [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3809)):
`git config --global --add safe.directory "*"`</sup>

Comment: As you mention in footnote 1: I needed to set the * in doubles quotes instead of single ones

Comment: I do wish there you provided a per project way of doing the same. none the less thank you.

Comment: why do you have to do things this complex?

Comment: @CrandellWS, there is. Only add the project directory you want to disable the security measure for: `git config --global --add safe.directory c:/Users/CrandellWS/projects/wonky-user-project`

Comment: If you're getting this error on _GitHub Actions_ or similar, you should replace `--global` with `--system`. [See GH Actions issue](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/1169)

Comment: On Windows, using `takeown` is the better answer, however

Comment: Odd git config --global --add safe.directory * did not work in my case, but system-wide did: git config --system --add safe.directory *.

Comment: I don't think that theoretical sentence is correct. Non-root users can get hacked and cause root user to run a malicious code (via git hooks etc.). I know this means you already have a malicious code issue before the safe.directory kicks in, but at least it will protect you against running that malicious code with the root user.

Comment: I think that before silencing warnings, one should clearly understand why this error message is appearing in the first place. If you know the problem, you can fix the problem, not put bandaids on it. And the problem is usually incorrect ownership and/or permissions. Take ownership, fix permissions - all is fixed without any hacks. Only if you specifically have a case where the parent dir containing the `.git` dir is shared because multiple users are using this repo on this machine (or shared drive), then and only then you should add the *specific* dir to safe dir config.

Comment: Thanks this actually helped me. Due to this VSCode was not showing the branch status bar. After adding this worked.

Answer (score 120):

I got the same issue and fixed it by changing the owner for the directory, e.g.,

```
chown -R <current_user> <repo_folder>
```

Comment: Could we set the user running the ansible module instead ?

Comment: I thought about this but I am using a Linux development machine which has a single specific user that needs to own the files and I add myself to that group... I suppose i could log into that account or `su` into it ... I do wish there was a way I could add the extra user as safe and not the file system...

Comment: `-R` descends directories `recursively`, changing the ownership for each file.

Comment: What should `<current_user>` be? Is it my user login name when I log in to the operating system, or is it this long-ass fucking code that starts with `S-1-5-21` and then is followed by 9+10+10+4 additional digits separated by hyphens? This is the code that Git tells me that the current user is after it tells me that it has detected a dubious ownership in the repository.

Comment: git config --global --add safe.directory * also did not work in my case, Altering permissions. I encountered this message via gitlist (a git web based tool) through the browser. I executed a 'chown -R www:www' on all the gitlist files and the REPO. www obviously not ideal (and will change) - but this post uncovered the issue I was facing.
Also, executing the following, system-wide works (without the permission change fix):
git config --system --add safe.directory '*'

Comment: @HelloGoodbye If you're on Windows, search for "How To Take Ownership of a Windows Folder or File" and follow the steps. In my experience, using UNIX-like tools (e.g. `chown` from Cygwin or Git for Windows) to mess with Windows permission may lead to further issues. But if you want to try, just use `chown -R path`. Owner is an optional argument, the default is current user anyway.

Answer (score 42):

If the same problem occurs on [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS)/Windows, make sure the parent folder of the `.git` and `.git` folder itself are both owned by the exact user you run `git.exe` from.

Just the same group (Administrators) or changing only the parent may not work.

Permissions can be edited via right-click on the folder(s) → Properties → Security Tab → Advanced (bottom right of the window) → Owner.
Possibly disabling inheritance will be required, done in the same window. [This Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/1062387/advanced-permissions-not-editable-in-windows-10) has hints.

The user you run `git.exe` from can be checked in [Resource Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Monitor): Task Manager → Performance → Open Resource Monitor (on bottom). May require enabling hidden "User Name" column.
If Git related executables are missing there, make a dummy Fetch or Pull while Resource Monitor is opened to ensure they were added.

Comment: This worked but it's not clear how to find the username. Inside the Resource Monitor I added the User Name column under processor/CPU (not sure what term is used in English versions of Windows). Furthermore you need to know what to look for. I noticed that a lot of processes were running from my Windows username, so I tried that name. Now when changing owner I typed that username in the text field and then pressed the "Check username" button, and the username was appended to the computer name such as MyComputer\MyUsername. Doing this on project folder and .git folder solved the problem.

Comment: What was supposed here - user of git.exe process or if git is used from other wrapper like MSVS or SourceTree (and not running), then user of such wrapper process.

Comment: In Windows Explorer, View tab > Show/hide > Show Hidden items

Comment: I had this problem because I ran my command prompt as an Administrator.  So, every "git clone" I did from the command line created the folder with the owner being the 'Administrators Group'.  When I tried to do any activities using a GUI application (which were launched from my account context) I would get this error.  Very annoying.

Comment: git config --global --add safe.directory * also did not work in my case, but altering the permissions per your post did - thanks! I encountered this message via gitlist (a git web based tool) through the browser. I executed a 'chown -R www:www' on all the gitlist files and the REPO. www obviously not ideal (and will change) - but this post uncovered the issue I was facing.
Also, executing the following, system-wide works (without the permission change fix):
git config --system --add safe.directory '*'

Answer (score 38):

If the OS is Windows, you have to take the ownership of the file with the command

```
takeown /F <dir/*> /R
```

`/F` parameter is the file, with the * wildcard character will apply to all files and folder;

`/R` parameter means recursive. It applies the owner to the current logged user to all files and subfolders too

`<dir/*>` is the directory to take ownership of.

Comment: Or if using the GUI: right click the folder - properties - security - advanced - click "change" in "owner" - select your username - ok - check "replace owner on subcontainers and objects".

Comment: I tried the command, but it didn't work. I had error that "The '<' operator is reserved for future use." I use "takeown /F * /R" with success.

Comment: Thanks, this fixes scoop not updating itself.

Comment: To complete the comment by @EndyTjahjono, you can find your username with the command `whoami`.

Comment: Note that `<dir/*>` is just a placeholder. You're expected to put the file/directory name or a `*` wildcard there, e.g. `takeown /F scoop /R`

Comment: Depending on the file system? [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) only? Or something else?

Comment: OK, the OP has probably [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than a month ago"*

Answer (score 12):

I ran the below command in [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) to solve it:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory C:/User/username/source/myproject
```

Close and reopen Visual Studio Code if required.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you are using the **correct terminal user**. For me, I had temporarily changed to the *root* user which would have caused issues. I changed back to the standard user with `su git-user` and the error went away.

Comment: Same with windows. Was running from cmd as Administrator in the begining, then accidentally run cmd as user and got that error

Answer (score 8):

Create a new directory on your disk where your current user is the owner of this new directory. In this new directory, clone your Git repo.

Answer (score 7):

I've got the same error message on Ubuntu/[LEMP](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-22-04) when executing Git's commands from PHP. Nothing suggested in previous answers helped to fix problem.

**Solution:**
You need to set correct owner of the hidden '.git' folder.

In my case, Git commands were executed by the 'www-data' user (which is a web server user):

```
sudo chown www-data:<current_user> -R .git
```

To restore the ability to work with Git from the command line, you need to allow the group to write:

```
sudo chmod g+w -R .git
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that two folders are being checked by Git: the `.git` folder and the folder containing it. Both must be owned by the current user. The other folders and files of the folder containing the `.git` folder can be owned by other users if there is a need. Therefore

1. Check the current user, e.g., run [`whoami`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whoami)
2. Check the owner of the `.git` folder, e.g. run `ls -al .git`
3. Evaluate the impact of changing the ownership of the `.git` folder if it is not the current user. If you want to also change the group, you might want to check what groups a user is in, e.g., running `id -Gn username` or `groups username`
4. Update the owner of the Git repository if it is safe by running `sudo chown current_user:appropriate_group .git` with the appropriate `current_user` and `appropriate_group`, e.g. run `sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu .git`
5. Check the owner of the folder containing the `.git` folder, e.g., run `ls -al ./`
6. Evaluate the impact of changing the ownership of that folder if it is not the current user. If you want to also change the group, you might want to check what groups a user is in, e.g., running `id -Gn username` or `groups username`
7. Update the ownership of that folder by running `sudo chown current_user:appropriate_group ./` with the appropriate `current_user` and `appropriate_group`, e.g., run `sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu ./`

Ensure that if you do change the owner of the folder containing the `.git` folder that permissions are still setup to work as you prefer, i.e. whether the previous owner retains the same read, write and execute permissions with the current group and everyone permissions. If they have lost permissions, either consider adjusting the group or other or revert the folder ownership change and use the `git config --global --add safe.directory path/to/repository` solution instead.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to restore the ownership. For example:

```
sudo chown -v "$( id -u; ):$( id -g; )" .;
sudo chown -v "$( id -u; ):$( id -g; )" -R .git;
find '.git' -type d -exec chmod -v 775 {} \;;
find '.git/objects' -type f -exec chmod -v 444 {} \;;
find '.git/hooks' -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec chmod -v 775 {} \;;
find '.git' -type f ! -path '.git/objects/*' ! -path '.git/hooks/*' -exec chmod -v 664 {} \;;
```

---

Related: [ensure_valid_ownership()](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.39.0/setup.c#L1144)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in when with Windows I used the solution  [provided by Kaustubh Navale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72978485/git-submodule-update-failed-with-fatal-detected-dubious-ownership-in-repositor/75985481#75985481) up in the answers and it worked for me.

I just run this and the problem was solved:

```
git config --global safe.directory '*'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you clone a repository with a given user and then try to pull changes with a different user, the error arises.
Change the user to the user you cloned the repository with, like this:

```
su <user>
```

Then proceed, for instance,

```
git pull
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

If you need this working for service users not having a home directory - like, e.g., *www-data*, you should consider to Git configuration it via Git system configuration:

`sudo git config --system --add safe.directory /my/repos/repofolder`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Sublime Merge](https://www.sublimemerge.com/) on Windows and you just want to silence this warning, you need to edit the **gitconfig** file used by Sublime Merge, which is usually located in the installation directory in the *Git\etc* subdirectory (something like *C:\Program Files\Sublime Merge\Git\etc\gitconfig*).
There you can add the *[safe]* section (if not already present) and either the suggested path, or the wildcard '*', as suggested by other answers.

See an example below:

```
[safe]
    directory = *
```

or

```
[safe]
    directory = 'C:/Users/Username/Projects/Whatever'
```

Of course you can add multiple directories.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with a library from the vendor folder. I just deleted the folder of the library and reinstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this problem in [Phabricator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phabricator), here is the solution that worked for me.

**Background:** Phabricator was working fine for me until this happened. When I open any repository to get the clone URL it throws me this error:

> fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/var/repo/3'

**Solution:** I checked the permissions and ownership of directory */var/repo* which was my current user. The Phabricator web server executes the commands using user "www-data".
I then changed the ownership of the "/var/repo" directory to the following:

```
sudo chown www-data:ubuntu -R repo/
```

After that it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the command you are running already failed once or there was a previous version of the package in the install folder, try removing the corresponding package's folder before trying again or look for further solutions. Here, `jhu3szh/serialize` for example if it corresponds to your package name.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered `fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at` using the Fork client on Windows against a repository in [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).
The solution was to open a Git console *inside Fork* (pointing at the Git Windows client used by Fork) and execute:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///wsl$/Ubuntu-22.04/home/username/code/my-repo-name'
```

Running the command inside WSL simply did not work as it changed `.gitconfig` inside WSL.

Answer (score 0):

This error is raised when you make an attempt to Git initialize (and then run any other Git command) a folder that is not child of `/home/my_user/`.

In your case, the folder is `serialize`, which is under `/media/...` .

You can stop the alert from being raised by just moving the folder under `/home/my_user/` .

Otherwise, you can also change the owner of `my_project_folder` , [as @Prakash Sahoo suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73018171/7658051).

Answer (score 0):

If you are lost, Git clone the file with different usernames. For example, try with `sudo git clone`. This gives ownership to `root`.

If you choose instead just `git clone`... then the ownership goes to the current `username`... One of them should work, likely you are mixing them up, and you need to type `sudo git branch -a` to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me after upgrading JetBrains' [Rider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#Rider) code editor. Before the upgrade, Rider was launched by a shortcut as Administrator. The upgrade removed the shortcut's configuration of "Run as Administrator" which caused Rider's Terminal to start giving me this Git error. Running the application (Rider) as Administrator again solved the Git issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) in your project location and run the below command for Windows OS for bypassing security.

```
git config --global safe.directory '*'
```

Comment: The top-rated answer already says this, with a lot more context. Please don't repeat answers.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, I ran the following command and then my problem was solved:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/MyPROJECT
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Why does it work?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, I solved the same problem simply by creating a copying of repository and using that instead.

In [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) (from a working directory outside of the repository):

```
cp -r <path-to-repository> <temporary-path>
rm -rf <path-to-repository>
mv <temporary-path> <path-to-repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved mine:

Run the following in your Android Studio terminal:

```
git config --list --global
```

After seeing duplicate directories listed, I decided to edit the global file by running:

```
git config --global --edit
```

My issue was with duplicate configurations in the *.gitconfig* global file listed. So I simply edited by deleting all of them till `[safe] directory = *` was left.

This configuration marks all directories as safe, provided you didn't install Git on a USB drive, but your local hard drive.

If you had set [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) as your default Git editor during installation, then simply save the Notepad++ file you just edited. Else, if the editing stayed in the console, simply type `:wq` to save and close the file after editing.

The last step is to restart your IDE(Android Studio in this case).
Use this video as a guide too [Git config tutorial. Where is the Git config file?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVia18FNHYo)

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here  worked for me; I ran:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory '*'
```

and

```
git config --system --add safe.directory '*'
```

and I was still getting the error in IntelliJ, because I was doing `git pull` using the admin User. The only solution that worked for me is to directly go to user page Path:

```
C:\Users\Your Username\\.gitconfig (add your username here)
```

and edit the `gitconfig` file. I added:

```
 [safe]
    directory = *
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `sudo` access, you can use the ownership:
`sudo -u OWNER git COMMAND`

Examples:
`sudo -u jenkins git status`
`sudo -u adam git clone ...`
...

Answer (score -1):

For me, the solution was to run the console (or [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements) in this case) as administrator.

Comment: this is almost always the wrong solution

Answer (score -9):

Just run using sudo : **sudo git status**

Comment: While this silences the warning, it fails to actually solve the underlying issue, and is not a good idea in the long term. Plus, not everybody can use sudo.

Comment: @joanis Okay, thanks for highlighting my mistake. i would request you to explain us the real RCA of this issue so we can understand this problem better. Thank you

Comment: These messages are always about file and directory ownership. There are good answers above addressing the underlying issue.