# Git repo returns dubious ownership when not run as admin

Tags: windows, git, git-for-windows

Last week I created a git repo for a project. This morning, I tried `git status` which results in `fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at 'C:/ProjectPath/ProjectName'`.

I believe I created the git repository using an administrator command prompt, so I tried `git status` in an administrator command prompt and it works. The same results happen when I use the Git Bash: it works when run as an administrator.

How can I change the repo's ownership to allow non-administrative usage? [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72978485/14493004) suggests multiple solutions using sudo; however, these are not applicable to git for windows: `sudo echo test` returns `bash: sudo: command not found`.

Comment: I would recommend to check permissions of the repo to make sure that you can read/write on it.... otherwise, the error message should display a command that would allow you to setup the repo to allow you to get access to it.

Comment: `git config --global --add safe.directory \path\to\project\` solved the problem. I'd prefer to have been able to change the file ownership, but couldn't find out how to properly find the user I wanted because of Azure AD.

Comment: `sudo` is for Unix-like systems. Windows has a much more complicated file permissions model than Unix-ish / POSIX; even POSIX ACLs don't cover all the Windows settings. I don't "do" Windows so I can't tell you how to fix it there, just that it's complicated.