# Git repository on network disk

Tags: git

Can't find a solution for my problem with Git.
I do use legacy guest system (Fedora Core 4) where my files are. I do share some folders via smb1 protocol and can successfully access them from Win11 host (same machine, using VMware).

My idea is to use FC4 to edit files (legacy system) use git from the win11. The reason for that is that FC4 support for SSL is outdated and I can't push commits to a remote repository.

I thought it will be straightforward, however when I try to do commit, I get

> fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '//192.168.57.128/work/'
> '//192.168.57.128/work/' is owned by:
> 'S-1-5-21-1030830248-2715341047-1655746900-2006'
> but the current user is:
> 'S-1-5-21-624182484-2203949050-1231800916-1001'
> To add an exception for this directory, call:
>
> ```
>    git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///192.168.57.128/work/'
> ```

and if I add the folder to safe I get the next error:

> warning: in the working copy of 'transfer-test.txt', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
> Rename from '.git/objects/45/tmp_obj_G4Fewr' to '.git/objects/45/b921b0f124da3f73017c56757858cdd6f1fa4a' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)

The file on the guest system r-xr--r-- even though the network share on Samba is configured to have create mask = 0775.

Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: The access permissions seem to be incorrect, see: [git submodule update failed with 'fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72978485/git-submodule-update-failed-with-fatal-detected-dubious-ownership-in-repositor).

Comment: If you have to use a shared folder for a repo - put a bare repository in it and clone from that locally. Using git in shared folders, especially smb, usually ends up with permission issues.

Comment: @fredrik the problem is, that I will continue to work on my guest system ( FC4 ) and the changes done in FC4 I want to commit via my host system and push them to Remote so that another team member can fetch them and make them available for their 'guest system'

Comment: Your bare repo can be a clone of another repo, with a remote. From your host system you can then push the changes on to the other hosting service. Git is decentralized, so you can use any clone of a repo as remote but to avoid issues they should be bare clones.