# git: detected dubious ownership in Azure Blob Storage mapped on a Azure VM

Tags: git, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine, git-config, git-for-windows

When I run `git status`, `git branch --track`, `git fetch --all`, `git pull --all` inside a git repository stored inside an **Azure Blob Storage** mapped to an **Azure virtual machine** with **Windows 11** and **Git for Windows version 2.37.3**, I get the following error:

```
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '<path>'
'<path>' is owned by:
'S-1-5-18'
but the current user is:
'S-1-5-21-1990399924-2863569968-2306271318-500'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

        git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///<path>'
```

I have tested:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///<path>'
```

and

```
git config --global --add safe.directory '*'
```

and change directories and files permissions:

```
TAKEOWN /F * /R
```

But when I do all this in a local folder of the virtual machine everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce same in my environment I got the error like below.***

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/AqUPS02.png)]

> **This error usually occurs When git will determine whether the current user is the owner of the git repository folder. if not, it will display the error like below because if the folder is not owned by the currently logged-in user, harmful files may be added there by other users.**

To resolve the issue:

You can make use of this command.

```
git config --global --add safe.directory <path>
```

As you tested above command already, try the below workaround:

***Select the folder of the git warehouse. If this folder is full of git warehouses, you can select the entire folder or select your file -> properties -> security -> advanced like below:***

[image]

If the owner is not same as current windows login account, click to change.

[image]

[image]

Click Find Now and search your current account name and click okay.

[image]

[image]

Refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72978485/git-submodule-update-failed-with-fatal-detected-dubious-ownership-in-repositor)  by *halt9k* to disable inheritance.

When I tried to use git status or git log now error doesn't occur like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.44 (Q1 2024) will be more helpful with this error message.

In addition to (rather cryptic) Security Identifiers, it will now show username and domain in the error message when it barfs on a mismatch between the Git directory and the current user on Windows.

See [commit f755e09](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f755e092e8bf22e7bf3599d59a6a7fa562f6b61b) (08 Jan 2024) by [Sören Krecker (`soerenkrecker-baader`)](https://github.com/soerenkrecker-baader).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b5fb623](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5fb62354213384d5f443c2cd835670407a3a2da), 19 Jan 2024)</sup>

> ### [`mingw`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f755e092e8bf22e7bf3599d59a6a7fa562f6b61b): give more details about unsafe directory's ownership
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Sören Krecker</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Johannes Sixt</sup>

> Add domain/username in error message, if owner sid of repository and user sid are not equal on windows systems.
>
> Old error message:
>
> ```
> fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at 'C:/Users/test/source/repos/git' 'C:/Users/test/source/repos/git' is owned by:
>     'S-1-5-21-571067702-4104414259-3379520149-500'
> but the current user is:
>     'S-1-5-21-571067702-4104414259-3379520149-1001'
> To add an exception for this directory, call:  
>
>     git config --global --add safe.directory C:/Users/test/source/repos/git
> ```
>
> New error message:
>
> ```
> fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at 'C:/Users/test/source/repos/git' 'C:/Users/test/source/repos/git' is owned by:
>     DESKTOP-L78JVA6/Administrator (S-1-5-21-571067702-4104414259-3379520149-500)
> but the current user is:
>     DESKTOP-L78JVA6/test (S-1-5-21-571067702-4104414259-3379520149-1001)
> To add an exception for this directory, call:  
>
>     git config --global --add safe.directory C:/Users/test/source/repos/git
> ```