# fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/github/workspace' in github action for Firebase app-distribution

Tags: android-studio, github, github-actions, firebase-app-distribution

I am trying to create a CI/CD pipeline for Android project. What I want to achieve is to upload the debug build in Firebase App distribution when the github Action is triggered.

I am using https://github.com/marketplace/actions/firebase-app-distribution-action#firebase-app-distribution-github-action to upload the build in app distribution

I have  also tried https://github.com/marketplace/actions/firebase-app-distribution

but getting the same issue in both the cases

Attaching the ScreenShot of the error getting during the github Action
[image: Github Action Error]

Here is my workflow yaml file

```
name: Workflow_1

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ dev ]
    types:
      - closed


jobs:
  build:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # checking out the code to the environment
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: set up Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          distribution: 'adopt'
          java-version: 11

      - name: Make gradlew executable
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew

#      - name: Build debug APK
#        run: ./gradlew assembleDebug

#      - name: Upload Debug APKs
#        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
#        with:
#          name: Test-App
#          path: app/build/outputs/
        
      - name: Firebase App Distribution3
        uses: hasretsariyer/firebase-app-distribution-github-action@v1.0
        with:
          app_id: "${{ secrets.FIREBASE_APP_ID }}"
          firebase_token: "${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}"
          app_file: app-debug.apk
          tester_groups: demoGRP
```

I searched the web not getting this issue linked with github Action.

### Update:

By guessing from the comments below, I edited the checkout part in yaml file

```
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          set-safe-directory: '*'
```

which lead to another issues: (Screenshot below)
[image: github repo error]

Comment: I believe that you already created an issue for this on the repo, right? https://github.com/hasretsariyer/firebase-app-distribution-github-action/issues/4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git submodule update failed with 'fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72978485/git-submodule-update-failed-with-fatal-detected-dubious-ownership-in-repositor)

Comment: Apart from the above similar question, please take a look at https://github.com/actions/checkout#usage. You may test with its `path` first to automatically create a parent directory under `GITHUB_WORKSPACE` root directory. See if that works. Otherwise, it also provides a `set-safe-directory` configuration so that you don't have run it manually, though it's default is `true` so it should already be working.

Comment: @Azeem yes, i did created issue in repo, didn't get any response there yet.
+ I checked the web, and the message to add safe.directory in gitConfig is bit confusing, as how changing any config in my local machine can have any effect in github repo as there is no changes to commit.

Comment: @Azeem checked the action/checkout#usage but couldn't figure out the way out

Comment: Right. That command was to run in the workflow, not on your local clone. Did you try with `checkout: path:` config?

Comment: Is `app-debug.apk` in the current directory? In the above commented `upload-artifact` step, the path is `app/build/outputs/`. Have you verified this part? Also, the step "Build debug APK" is also commented. From the docs (https://github.com/hasretsariyer/firebase-app-distribution-github-action#app_file) for `app_file`, it should be the path to where the built `.apk` or `.ipa` file resides.