# Git tools not available in PhpStorm

Tags: git, phpstorm

In PhpStorm (version 2023.1), when I want to look at the history of a file, it gives me this message :

`detected dubious ownership in repository`

Please note that, for security reasons, I am not allowed to edit the "safe.directory" line in my git config file. Also, I use a VM to work on my projects.

Does anybody have any idea how I can resolve this problem, please?

I already tried to change the "safe.directory" line in my git config but it is not allowed by my organization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be linked to the version of Git installed locally.
I have installed version 2.25.1 and it works again.

Answer (score 0):

IDE relies on command-line git and more likely you would have the same error in command-line.

Please see explanation and possible solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73100228/12360005