# Azure deployment fails with: 'fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at'

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm working with a ASP.NET application and I deploy using Azure and Git. It's set to trigger deployment when the Master branch gets pushed to.

I've successfully done this in the past but it's failing now.  I can successfully push my code to GitHub where it appears each time, but it fails to deploy on Azure.

From the Deployment Center, I see that the commit id is prefaced with "temp" like "temp-XXXXXX".  It also leaves an error message in the log details that says:

```
"fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at _______ is owned by: ________ 
but the current owner is _______. 

git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///____________________'\n\r\nC:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe 
remote add -t master origin "git@github.com:_____"
```

(The blanked out info is full IP addresses with subdirectories and repository names, I didn't think it mattered because this seems like a generic issue)

I tried adding the parent directory to `safe.directory` using the exact command that they provided, but received an error of "no such file or directory: %(prefix)///_________________.

According to my local file system, I'm already the owner of the directory.

I tried following some of the steps outlined in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72978485/git-submodule-update-failed-with-fatal-detected-dubious-ownership-in-repositor), but I am reluctant to do `git config --global --add safe.directory '*'` because it is a shared repository.

Could this issue be caused by Azure itself? Do I need to grant Azure permissions somehow?

Thanks

Comment: I am also getting the same error, I attempted a deploy from BitBucket (Git) to Azure on 6th Sept and it failed. Last successful one before that was 31st Aug. I have a feeling Azure has changed something!

Comment: FYI, there's a thread discussing this over on Microsoft Learn, seems a few people have been experiencing this issue since 31st August, MS are aware: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1361529/azure-web-app-deployment-now-failing-with-detected

Comment: Nice, thanks. @Peter something that's worked for me is using Visual Studio publish, if you use Visual Studio for your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide an update, there was a bug identified. The fix has been rolled out by our product engineering team.
(tracked on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1361529/azure-web-app-deployment-now-failing-with-detected?orderby=helpful#answers) my answer)

Answer (score 0):

***I recommend using the steps below:-***

Make sure you run this command to add the repository in the safe list like below:-

```bash
git config --global --add safe.directory 'C:\Users\sid24desai\source\repos\WebApplication6'
```

***And then try pushing your code again by adding correct git remote url like below:-***

```bash
git remote -v
```

```bash
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/sid24desai/WebApplication6
```

[image]

[image]

**And in order to resolve the error Check this [SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72978485/git-submodule-update-failed-with-fatal-detected-dubious-ownership-in-repositor) by Stinn and halt9k**

Then I tried deploying a sample **`.NET application`** in Azure Web app with **`.NET 6.0 framework`** and it got deployed successfully like below:-

**My github action workflow:-**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - valleywebapp832

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '6.0.x'
          include-prerelease: true

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: .net-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'valleywebapp832'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_CD4EC59DD26349C09FBA41C085A9BEBF }}
          package: .
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but just from the first step when I try to run the `git config --global --add safe.directory %(prefix)....` command they provided, I get a "no such file or directory" error from my terminal.  I've also tried adding the repo's folder and the path to the repo's folder as safe directories, but it has no effect.

Comment: The remote URL is correct as well