How not to "You've added another git repository inside your current repository."
I wanted to restart a new git on github.  I am using Ubuntu 22.04  According to this post, I thought I could simply delete my current .git dir and restart from scratch. My web app resides at /home/example-development/htdocs/development.example.com/app_dir. I have done the following:
rm -rf .git/ 
git init

Then I received this alert:
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/example-development/htdocs/development.example.com/app_dir/.git/

Next I issued this command:
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/example-yellowsnow.git
But then I received the following:
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/home/example-development/htdocs/development.example.com/app_dir'

So I executed the following:
git config --global --add safe.directory /home/example-development/htdocs/development.example.com/app_dir

But then I received the following alert:
You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
I really wanted to start afresh with a new repository.

As mentioned in this SO post: (1) "git submodule update" failed with 'fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at...' the issue can also be related to ownership of the files in your working directory. By running the following command you can take a look at the ownership of the working folder
ls -ld /home/example-development/htdocs/development.example.com/app_dir

And if you would want to change the ownership, (which was also mentioned in the SO post (1)) you can run the following command
sudo chown -R <current_user> /home/example-development/htdocs/development.example.com/app_dir

Further you can ensure that there are no .git folders in your working directory by displaying all occurences by using:
find /home/example-development/htdocs/development.example.com/app_dir -type d -name .git

and then by removing them just like you did with rm -rf /path/to/found/.git you should be able to remove all existing local repositories.
Then by running git init you should have a new local repository. It might be worth reading the explanation here as well on what the safe directory does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73100228/8204677

Thank you very much for your detailed reply.  Reading through now.  Thank you!  What exactly triggers the "dubious ownership" alert and why did I end up with a repository in a repository?  Cannot seem to under this.

Ney, change all the file permissions to match the site user.  Removed the .git dir.  Ensured no other git dir present.  I still get:  hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.

My mistake. There indeed was a nested .git.  Have deleted it and all ok now.  Thank you.

@spreaderman, I think the dubious ownership mostly is caused by differentiating user permissions in folders! Meaning that if user A owns the folder but user B runs git status for instance - then we would receive the dubious ownership message!

@spreaderman of course! Was the find command helpful in finding the nested git? :D I am happy it was resolved for you!

Yes, the "find" was the key.  Really appreciated!
